# angularchart.js stacked bar chart colors

Tags: colors, bar-chart, stacked, angular-chart

I'm working with an elementary example of stacked bar chart. I would like to define a different color for every series (apple, banana, ...).
However when I try to set `chart-colors=["#aaa","#bbb",...]` I get random colors as result.

Here is my example:

http://plnkr.co/edit/NWKM85zV5wgwtHu17gtX?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

After debuging the angular-chart.js I figured out that all the colors are converted to RGB representation in function `hexToRgb(hex)` and this function does not support short HEX format `#FFF` but rather long `#FFFFFF`

Following code worked well

```
chart-colors="['#ffffff', '#ff0000', '#00ff00', '#0000ff']"
```